# Saving the File with name as last 6 characters/digits of URL when opened on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, url

I have 100s of URL of form: `https://example.com/abcd/xyz?q=123456` (last 6 digits of URL varies according to file) this when opened on browser starts downloading a pdf file with name "File.pdf". I plan to open 100s of URLs at once using some extension. It saves them as "File.pdf", "File (1).pdf" and so on.

Is there any when I open URL, it saves as "123456.pdf" for given above URL, and similarly based on last 6 digits of URL other files get saved as well.

I looked up 2-3 chrome extension but didn't help me resolve my issue.

Comment: Are you on Windows/Linux/MacOS?

Comment: @harrymc, On Windows Sir.